# How To Pass Two Parameters In "Client.WriteLine" In "SimpleTCP"

Tags: c#, .net, chat

So I want to make a chat application in C# using the NuGet module "SimpleTCP", I made it work so the clients can send messages to the server and all clients get those messages but what I want now is to make it so I could pass a name string in the `client.WriteLine("Message")` when I send a message to the server telling a message was sent("client" is my "SimpleTcpClient" variable). 
The problem is that the `"WriteLine()"` function get only ONE argument so it can't get a Message and Name variables.

I have tried searching google for a solution for that but found nothing.
I also tried just doing `"client.WriteLine("This is a message", "Tal M")"` but it didn't work.

This is some of the code that tells the client to send a message to the server:

```cs
private void SendMessageInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client.WriteLine(MessageInput.Text);
}
```

This is the lines that makes the server get the message and broadcast it to all other(including the client that send the message) clients:

```
private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
{
    txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
        server.Broadcast(String.Format(e.MessageString));
    });
}
```

What I expect is to be able to get a message that includes Two arguments; First one for a message(String), and Second one for a name(String). I would really appreciate getting help, Thanks.

Comment: well you are right there is no `WriteLine` method that 2 arguments on top of my head u have to create an extension method to serve ur needs. Its going to be tricky.

Comment: You can send any string with the client, so it is up to you that that string contains all informations. You could send a JSON object with two properties as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for my problem! All I had to do is just format the String that I send so it would include both Name and Message using `client.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", "Bob", "Hello World"))`.
This solution isn't great since I might need to change it to actually get the Name and Message as variables. If I would want to do that I would need to send a JSON object which can work really well but I don't want to do it now(This solution was suggested by @Sir Rufo, Thanks for the help.